# bot.sendMessage is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm currently making a discord bot that will send out messages. Unfortunately the messages are receiving errors such as `bot.sendMessage` is not a function. I'm fairly new to coding so this one has me stumped. Even any google searches have not been able to help me to the point where I can understand it.

I've tried `bot.send` as maybe `.sendMessage` is now outdated I had read somewhere I believe.

```
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket(dataUrl);
    bot.send({to: flowChannel,message: 'Websocket connected'});
exampleSocket.onopen = function (event) {
logger.info('got to here');
```

The output should post in my channel that the websocket connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```js
> bot.send({to: flowChannel,message: 'Websocket connected'});
> ```

`Client.sendMessage()` was removed in Discord.js 9.0 back in 2016.

> I've tried `bot.send` as maybe `.sendMessage` is now outdated I had read somewhere I believe.

`TextBasedChannel.sendMessage()`, `TextBasedChannel.sendCode()`, `TextBasedChannel.sendEmbed()`, `TextBasedChannel.sendFile()`, and `TextBasedChannel.sendFiles()` are all deprecated.

---

The equivalent of your code today is as follows...

```js
flowChannel.send('Websocket connected')
  .catch(console.error); // Catch the rejected promise in the event of an error.
```

---

*[Discord.js Docs (Stable)](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)*

Answer (score 0):

`#sendMessage` is deprecated.

You need to pass `'message'` through and use `message.channel.send()`

Channel can also be a DM.

Answer (score 0):

[`TextChannel.sendMessage`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=sendMessage) (and [`DMchannel.sendMessage`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=sendMessage)) along with all type of `sendXX` functions, is deprecated.

The function `TextBasedChannel.send` take as argument a [`MessageOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions) value (or directly an `Attachment` or `RichEmbed`) if you want to pass anything other than just text.

To access the `send` function, you need a `TextChannel` or a `DMchannel` which you can get:

- In the message that triggered your function like this: `client.on('messages', (msg) => {msg.channel.send('Hello')})`
- If you have a [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) instance: `guild.channels.get('channel id')` or `guild.channels.find(d => d.name === '<channel name>)')` (*note: you'll have to check if the channel is a TextChannel and not a voice one*)
- with the [`Client.channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=channels) method, which list *all of the Channels that the client is currently handling, mapped by their IDs - as long as sharding isn't being used, this will be every channel in every guild, and all DM channels*